# Render time problem on character animation

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine

When I woke up this morning I opened my last project but I started to want to render an image containing my animated character, rendering became extremely long or even impossible. Yesterday I did not have this problem while I did not modify it.

I'm sure the problem comes from the character because when I hide it the problem no longer occurs.

I don't understand but maybe one of you can help me...

I attach the .blend right here: https://app.box.com/s/peg6wb0l4h3q5bhwheih9d8xa4tyfnf1

Thanks in advance !

PS: I'm using 3.0

Comment: It seems like the problem is not happening when i disable the Motion Blur.
The fact that it is due to the character and the motion blur, i think the reason is coming from an not wanted movement from something in the character that the motion blur is not able to calculate or to understand.
If someone knows..

Comment: I've also seen that sometimes rendering time gets crazy when the movement of an object is not continuous and jump from a position to a completely different one (motion blur doesn't understand).
The problem is that it doesn't happen in my animation so perhaps there is a bug in a vertex or armature animation...